# Download file from remote file server to local machine using curl php

Tags: php, file, curl, download, remote-server

I am trying to create a link to download a file from remote file server to local machine. 
Right now i am Curl code that i found in stackoverflow. The code works with file path with localhost C drive. But fails with url to remote file. 
What is wrong with the URL? The commented URL works. Code:

```
$url  = 'file://v1/cos/EA QA/Test Results/SS/4.6.1/CD06/SS 4.6.1 TestResults.xlsm';
// $url  = 'file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/qrd/test/SS 4.6.1 TestResults.xlsm';
$path = 'C:/test/SS 4.6.1 TestResults.xlsm';     
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
if ($data == FALSE){
    echo "Failed in 1.";
} else {
    $file = fopen($path, "wb");
    fputs($file, $data);
    echo "hi1";
}
fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because

```
file://v1/cos/EA QA/
```

is not a valid path, looks like a network path. Try uploading the file to a webserver and test it or provide a proper `ip address` of the network.

Your remote server should have an ip address. Try that like
`http://192.159.23.2XX/TestResults.xlsm` as your URL

Comment: Even after substituting ip addr for the remote server name it doesnt work, it fails. URL being used is file://192.150.xx.xx/cos/EA QA/Test Results/SS/4.6.1/CD06/...
I have tried both file:// and http://. Both failed.

Comment: What happens when you paste `http://192.150.xx.xx/cos/EA QA/Test Results/SS/4.6.1/CD06/...` on your browser ?

Comment: http URL causes the following error in Chrome :
Error code: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
But with file URL the browser opens a download dialog box.

Comment: I can download a file from a Windows remote host with a similar URL with file:// header. But couldnt download from the remote file server.

Comment: What error you get when you try `file://192.150.xx.xx/cos/EA QA/Test Results/SS/4.6.1/CD06/` using `cURL` ?

Answer (score 0):

ALternatively you can use file_get_contents

```
   $data = file_get_contents('C:/test/SS 4.6.1 TestResults.xlsm');
```

Or if you really wanna use CURL you got to have your file in a valid http protocol.

```
  e.g $url = 'http://192.159.23.2XX//TestResults.xlsm';
```